# Was William Campbell both married and having another relationship?

Tags: 19th-century, scotland

William Campbell born 1816/1819 Creich, Sutherland, Scotland, was the husband of Elspeth Matheson (born 1820 Rogart, sutherland) and had 6 children and as far as I can  ascertain had a relationship with Eliza Campbell at the same time and had 9 children.

He was a missionary and preacher of the Free Church and they moved a great deal.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Do you have baptism records for all 15 children naming a William Campbell as the father?  Do you have any marriage records for a William Campbell around the right time and location?

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this already but are you quite certain that Elspeth and Eliza are not the same person, since the names are so similar? In these cases it really helps to include all the relevant evidence. What records do you have that shows he was having two relationships? You can [edit] your question to add information. Otherwise we will probably be telling you things you already know, which is not useful for you or us.

Comment: According to Wikipedia [Cambell is the seventh most common surname in Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell_(surname)), and William is a very common Christian name so I think you will need to take much care not to confuse two (or more) men of the same name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please take a moment to look at the information in the [help] about [how to ask a good question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Since we don't know what sources you have so far, it's difficult for us to answer without re-doing all your searches.  Could you give us a brief list of what you've looked at to get the information in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks  for all your answers.  No I don't have any baptism certificates for any of them.  I have looked at registers and other information that people have.  I am pretty sure they are different people.

Comment: Elspeth is a Scottish variation of the name Elizabeth, so it is possible that there is only one family. However, it is also possible that there are two families as you suspect. What information do you have on the two families - have you found them on a census, for example?

Comment: I think you should list all baptism/birth details you have for the 15 children and include the exact spelling used in those records for their names and those of their parents.

Comment: William Campbell B1816/1819 Creich, Sutherland / Dornoch
'51 Farmers Son Badbea '61 Missionary 12 Bank St  '71 Free Church Mission. Upper Tenahann '81 Mission. Lanarkshire '91 Preacher 16 Beufoy Street Caithness '41 census live Trantle Begg
Elspeth Matheson B1820, Rogart, Sutherlan. '48 Jane Campbell, Evanton '50 Christina Campbell Blair Athole '57 Georgina Campbell Lochalsh '59 John Campbell Lochalsh, '63 Barbara Campbell Lochalsh 1865 Isabella Campbell, Urquhart Inverness-shire  Res '41 Sutherlan '51 Creich, '61 Lochalsh '71 Urquhart, Ross & Cromarty '81 Glasgow Anderston '91 Wick Caithnes

Comment: William Campbell B1819 / 1816 Creich, Sutherland / Dornoch
Children by Eliza Campbell: 1843 Jessie Mitchell Campbell, Lairg, 1845 July 12th George Campbell, Lairg;1848 Jean Campbell, Evanton, Kiltearn,or Blair Atholl; 1850 May Christina Campbell, Blair Atholl, Perthshire; 1852 Donald Robert Campbell, Blair Atholl, 1853 Alexander Campbell, Kintail; 1855 Georgina Sophia Blair Campbell; 1857 John Kennedy Campbell, Kintail, Ross-shire; 1859 Alexandrina Campbell. Plockton, Ross-shire; 1863 Barbara Campbell, Plockton Ross-shire; 1865 Isabella Campbell, Urquart and Logie Wester, Ross & Cromarty